# copying remote master to local branch -git

Tags: git, git-pull

Hey I am working on a local branch on an Android Project.I want to replace all code on my local branch with all the code on the remote master.When I try to do `git pull origin master`,it tries to merge and pulls up conflicts to resolve,which is undesirable since I just want to simply replace everything.

Answer (score 1):

You want to reset to the last commit on your local branch that is on the remote with

`git reset --hard <sha of commit`

Then you can do `git pull origin master` and it only bring the changes from the remote.

If you are not sure what the commit is you can use

`git merge-base origin/master master`

That will give the SHA of the last common commit.  You can reset to that.

The other option is to delete the branch and re-checkout from the remote.